# Call to undefined method Opis\JsonSchema\Schema::fromJsonString()

Tags: php, json

This is my code. What could be wrong?

```
    $data1 = json_decode($data);
    $schema = Schema::fromJsonString(file_get_contents('JSONSchema_CC.json'));
    $validator = new Validator();
    /** @var ValidationResult $result */
    $result = $validator->schemaValidation($data1, $schema);
```

Comment: You appear to be using code targeting the 1.x version but have the 2.x version installed. Either downgrade or checkout their [migration guide](https://opis.io/json-schema/2.x/php-migration.html).

Comment: @ChrisHaas how do I downgrade?

Comment: Are you starting a new project or working on an existing one? If you are starting new, please don't downgrade and instead learn their new (and thus preferred) pattern. But if you really need to downgrade, you just need to tell composer that you want the old one using `composer require opis/json-schema:1.1`. You might need to remove the old one first.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I am working on an existing project..
It works now. Thanks a lot.